# Forcing HTTPS on nginx with exceptions

Tags: nginx

At the moment I'm forcing HTTPS with the following configuration in the server block.

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.domain.tld$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Now I'd like to add one excaption from this rule for "http://www.domain.tld/some/url" and just can't figure out a working config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
if ($request_uri != /some/url1) { 
    set $test  A; 
} 
if ($request_uri != /some/url2) { 
    set $test  "${test}B"; 
} 
if ($scheme = 'http') { 
    set $test  "${test}C"; 
} 
if ($test = ABC) { 
    rewrite ^ https://www.domain.tld$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Read [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) before you fill your configuration file with `if` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use two server blocks, one for secure and one for insecure connections.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /some/url {
        ...
    }
    ...
    include /path/to/common/config;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    include /path/to/common/config;
}
```

You can use an `include` directive to pull in common configuration from a separate file.